# Consultar valores com 0 incluídos no count() mesmo não tendo valores

Tags: sql, firebird

Estou precisando consultar a quantidade de notas emitidas com modelo 55 para criação de um relatório.
O problema é que eu estou precisando colocar valores zerados na coluna quantidade mesmo não tendo valor algum.

Ex:

```
empresa   filial   data   quantidade
  5         1     01/2012     30
  5         1     02/2012     42
  5         1     03/2012     30
  5         1     04/2012     52
  5         2     01/2012     33
  5         2     02/2012     42
```

Porém, eu consultei o ano inteiro, especificamente eu gostaria que ficasse assim:

```
empresa   filial   data   quantidade
  5         1     01/2012     30
  5         1     02/2012     42
  5         1     03/2012     30
  5         1     04/2012     52
  5         1     05/2012     0
  5         1     06/2012     0
  5         1     07/2012     0
  5         1     08/2012     0
  5         1     09/2012     0
  5         1     10/2012     0
  5         1     11/2012     0
  5         1     12/2012     0
  5         2     01/2012     33
  5         2     02/2012     42
  5         2     03/2012     0
  5         2     04/2012     0
  5         2     05/2012     0
  5         2     06/2012     0
  5         2     07/2012     0
  5         2     08/2012     0
  5         2     09/2012     0
  5         2     10/2012     0
  5         2     11/2012     0
  5         2     12/2012     0
```

Já tentei com `coalesce(quantidade, 0)`, `case when(quantidade is null) then quantidade = 0` e até algumas procedures, mas falhei miseravelmente.

Em resumo:
É possível "forçar" o `count()` informar também os valores nulos como 0 mesmo não tendo informação?

#### Edit:

Consultas sendo realizadas:
Como solicitado vou colocar como estou fazendo, ia colocar um código fictício, porém vou informar um real, acredito que fica mais claro.
Consulta SQL:

```
SELECT E.EMPRESA,F.NOMEFANTASIA,F.FILIAL,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM S.DATASAIDA)||'/'||EXTRACT(YEAR FROM S.DATASAIDA) AS DATASAIDA,
S.MODELO, COUNT(*) AS QUANTIDADE
FROM ES02_SAIDA S
INNER JOIN SC00_FILIAL F ON (F.IDFILIAL = S.IDFILIAL)
INNER JOIN SC00_EMPRESA E ON (E.IDEMPRESA = F.IDEMPRESA)
WHERE E.EMPRESA IN (:IDEMPRESA)
AND S.DATASAIDA BETWEEN ''||:DATAINI||'' AND ''||:DATAFIM||''
AND (S.MODELO = '55' OR  S.MODELO = '57')
GROUP BY E.EMPRESA,F.NOMEFANTASIA,F.FILIAL,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM S.DATASAIDA)||'/'||EXTRACT(YEAR FROM S.DATASAIDA),
S.MODELO
ORDER BY 5,1,2
```

Resultado:

```
EMPRESA  NOMEFANTASIA   FILIAL  DATASAIDA  MODELO  QUANTIDADE
  5  EMPRESA             1  1/2012     55              44  
  5  EMPRESA             1  2/2012     55              34  
  5  EMPRESA             1  3/2012     55              53  
  5  EMPRESA             1  4/2012     55              48  
  5  EMPRESA             1  5/2012     55              76  
  5  EMPRESA             1  6/2012     55              39  
  5  EMPRESA             1  7/2012     55              22  
  5  EMPRESA             1  8/2012     55              34  
  5  EMPRESA             1  9/2012     55              32  
  5  EMPRESA             1  10/2012    55              39  
  5  EMPRESA             1  11/2012    55              38  
  5  EMPRESA             1  12/2012    55              77  
  5  EMPRESA2            2  1/2012     55              38  
  5  EMPRESA2            2  2/2012     55              59  
  5  EMPRESA2            2  3/2012     55              53  
  5  EMPRESA2            2  4/2012     55               8
```

#### Edit 2:

Boa tarde, muito obrigado pela ajuda e tentativa de resolver minha questão.
Porém, volto com outro questionamento a vocês que seria sobre a utilização do `UNION`.
Estou utilizando o seguinte SQL:

```
SELECT TABELA.EMPRESA,
       TABELA.NOMEFANTASIA,
       TABELA.FILIAL,
       TABELA.DATASAIDA,
       TABELA.MODELO,
       COUNT(TABELA.MODELO) AS QUANTIDADE
FROM(
       SELECT E.EMPRESA,F.NOMEFANTASIA,F.FILIAL,
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM S.DATASAIDA)||'/'||EXTRACT(YEAR FROM S.DATASAIDA) AS DATASAIDA,
       S.MODELO, COUNT(*) AS QUANTIDADE
       FROM ES02_SAIDA S
       INNER JOIN SC00_FILIAL F ON (F.IDFILIAL = S.IDFILIAL)
       INNER JOIN SC00_EMPRESA E ON (E.IDEMPRESA = F.IDEMPRESA)
       WHERE E.EMPRESA IN (:IDEMPRESA)
       AND S.DATASAIDA BETWEEN ''||:DATAINI||'' AND ''||:DATAFIM||''
       AND (S.MODELO = '55' OR  S.MODELO = '57')
       group by 1,2,3,4,5
   UNION
       SELECT distinct NULL AS EMPRESA,'TOTAIS POR FILIAL' AS NOMEFANTASIA,F.filial AS FILIAL,
       null AS DATASAIDA,null as MODELO,
       --'QTD='||(SUM(1))||' MÉDIA= '||(SUM(1)/COUNT(S.modelo)) AS QUANTIDADE
       (SUM(1)/COUNT(S.modelo)) AS QUANTIDADE
       FROM ES02_SAIDA S
       INNER JOIN SC00_FILIAL F ON (F.IDFILIAL = S.IDFILIAL)
       INNER JOIN SC00_EMPRESA E ON (E.IDEMPRESA = F.IDEMPRESA)
       WHERE E.EMPRESA IN (:IDEMPRESA)
       AND S.DATASAIDA not BETWEEN ''||:DATAINI||'' AND ''||:DATAFIM||''
       AND (S.MODELO = '55' OR  S.MODELO = '57')
       group by 1,2,3,4,5
)TABELA
    GROUP BY
    TABELA.EMPRESA,
    TABELA.NOMEFANTASIA,
    TABELA.FILIAL,
    TABELA.DATASAIDA,
    TABELA.MODELO
       ORDER BY
       TABELA.FILIAL asc nulls last,
       TABELA.DATASAIDA asc nulls last,
       TABELA.EMPRESA asc nulls last
```

O resultado está trazendo os mesmos resultados do primeiro Edit, porém a quantidade está 1 em todos e 0 na linha totalizador.

```
EMPRESA  NOMEFANTASIA       FILIAL  DATASAIDA  MODELO  QUANTIDADE
  5  EMPRESA                 1       1/2012     55          1  
  5  EMPRESA                 1       10/2012    55          1  
  5  EMPRESA                 1       11/2012    55          1  
  5  EMPRESA                 1       12/2012    55          1  
  5  EMPRESA                 1       2/2012     55          1  
  5  EMPRESA                 1       3/2012     55          1  
  5  EMPRESA                 1       4/2012     55          1  
  5  EMPRESA                 1       5/2012     55          1  
  5  EMPRESA                 1       6/2012     55          1  
  5  EMPRESA                 1       7/2012     55          1  
  5  EMPRESA                 1       8/2012     55          1  
  5  EMPRESA                 1       9/2012     55          1  
     TOTAIS POR FILIAL       1                              0  
  5  EMPRESA                 2       1/2012     55          1  
  5  EMPRESA                 2       2/2012     55          1  
  5  EMPRESA                 2       3/2012     55          1  
  5  EMPRESA                 2       4/2012     55          1  
     TOTAIS POR FILIAL       2                              0
```

Era pra trazer 44,34,53... :(
Agradeço a todos pela ajuda

Comment: Olá Gaspar, você poderia postar um exemplo com alguns dados e uma consulta de exemplo (clique no link editar na sua pergunta)? 
Pelo visto você tem um `group by empresa, filial, data` correto? Geralmente isso envolve um `LEFT JOIN` com as datas... Mesmo que você tenha que gerar essa lista de "meses em cada ano" dinamicamente.

Comment: Me parece improvável de você conseguir isso. Se eu entendi direito você quer selecionar o que não tem. Se você emitir um comando especifico selecionando a data x então o retorno será nulo e você poderia tratar com o coalesce, mas se você pedir para agrupar, ele somará apenas os que existem, claro. Você precisa de uma outra tabela zerada e então poderá fazer join com ela ou de um case para colocar inteligência nesse select.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela ajuda Anthony e Reginaldo.
Eu não utilizei o `LEFT JOIN` porque não é uma coluna existente na tabela. Tentei fazer com um `LEFT JOIN ES02_SAIDA S2 ON (S2.IDSAIDA = S.IDSAIDA) ` mas também não deu muito certo.

Pois é, o `group by` está descartando os resultados que deveria informar.

Tentei também com `UNION` e também não deu certo...

Comment: Veja se ajuda http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/531584-como-trazer-os-resultados-zerados/

Comment: Realmente não deu, neste caso do jamersondr no fórum imasters. A lógica é por dias, e não confere data, apenas anos. Mesmo informando este caso nos 12 meses faria com que o `group by` desconsiderasse os valores zerados. Brigado pela informação

Comment: Consegui arrumar parcialmente a consulta. Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Para este tipo de problema, eu criei uma `procedure` que retorna os dias de um dado período:

```
SET TERM ^ ;

create or alter procedure DIAS_PERIODO (
    INICIO date,
    FIM date)
returns (
    DIA date)
as
begin
  DIA = :INICIO;
  WHILE (DIA <= :FIM) DO
  BEGIN
    suspend;
    DIA = DIA + 1;
  END
end^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Daí você pode fazer uma SQL nesse estilo:

```
select   count(t.ID),
         d.DIA
from     (select dia from DIAS_PERIODO('01.01.2017', '31.01.2017')) d left JOIN
         tramitacao t on t.DATA = d.DIA
group by d.dia
```

(SQL diferente da sua pois testei aqui com uma tabela do meu sistema que possui datas)

Resultado:

```
COUNT   DIA
0   01/01/2017
24  02/01/2017
23  03/01/2017
13  04/01/2017
22  05/01/2017
78  06/01/2017
0   07/01/2017
0   08/01/2017
55  09/01/2017
42  10/01/2017
27  11/01/2017
47  12/01/2017
94  13/01/2017
0   14/01/2017
0   15/01/2017
28  16/01/2017
101 17/01/2017
81  18/01/2017
49  19/01/2017
68  20/01/2017
0   21/01/2017
0   22/01/2017
90  23/01/2017
110 24/01/2017
89  25/01/2017
86  26/01/2017
126 27/01/2017
0   28/01/2017
0   29/01/2017
65  30/01/2017
154 31/01/2017
```

Answer (score 0):

utilizar `HAVING` antes do `order by` adicione `HAVING COUNT(*) = 0`.